# How to count same values in array c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to count the number of same elements on the net, I found this easy solution on the net but I am adjusting it so I understand it properly by myself.
I am trying to count how many number of 40 are there in the array. Which is 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<array>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int array[6] = {38,38,40,38,40,37};
    cout<<count(ca.begin(),ca.end(),40);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is that ca is not recognised, and here is the codes that I found to help work this counting. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/154188/

Comment: `array<int,6> ca{38,38,40,38,40,37};` is not the same as `int array[6] = {38,38,40,38,40,37};`.  You need to use the same code if you want to see it working.

Comment: What is `ca`? Did you mean to count `array` instead?

Comment: If you are going to use the example, then you should use the whole example. They have a `std::array<int> ca` *and you don't*.

Comment: @NathanOliver To be honest I did not understand what array<int,6> was so I just tried to recode it to understand.

Comment: You could, as an alternative, use std::begin(array) and std::end(array) rather than ca.begin() / end()

Comment: Then you should look it up.  Just changing a type and hoping it will work normally leads to errors.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев I am using that already.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев array.begin() doesn't exist for arrays.  std::begin(array) does though.

Comment: It's clear that you are looking for solution for some kind of a homework. As you don't know why you have error when using `count` you probably should write custom solution to your problem using only skills you have right now. I will gave you necessary knowledge for future programing lessons.

Comment: @EVERYONE, THANKS I FIGURED IT OUT :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you have linked to is using a `std::array` called `ca`.
It takes a type and number of elements, so `std::array<int, 6>` expects 6 `int`s and is a fixed length array.

This has a `begin` and `end` method and plays nicely with the algorithms in the stl.

If you have a C style array instead, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` to achieve the same thing.

```
array<int, 6> ca{ 38,38,40,38,40,37 };
cout << count(ca.begin(), ca.end(), 40) << '\n';

int c_style_array[] = { 38,38,40,38,40,37 };
cout << count(std::begin(c_style_array), std::end(c_style_array), 40) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not classes and do not have member functions. Moreover you have a typo. I think you mean

```
int ca[6] = {38,38,40,38,40,37};
cout<<count(ca.begin(),ca.end(),40);
```

Write either like

```
cout << count( ca, ca + sizeof( ca ) / sizeof( *ca ), 40 );
```

or include header `<iterator>`

```
#include <iterator>
```

and write

```
cout << count( begin( ca ), end( ca), 40 );
```

On the other hand if you will use class std::array instead of your array then you may write

```
array<int, 6> ca = {38,38,40,38,40,37};
cout<<count(ca.begin(),ca.end(),40);
```

Here I a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a1[6] = { 38, 38, 40, 38, 40, 37 };

    std::cout << std::count( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ), 40 ) << std::endl;

    std::array<int, 6> a2 = { 38, 38, 40, 38, 40, 37 };

    std::cout << std::count( a2.begin(), a2.end(), 40 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course `ca` is not recognized, you forgot to initialize it :)

The `count` function needs to receive the beginning and the end of the range over which you want to count. In your case, the array begins at `array`, and ends at `array+5`, but it's a strict comparison so you must pass `array+6`.

The `main` becomes:

```
int main(){
    int myArray[] = {38,38,40,38,40,37};

    cout << count(myArray, myArray+6 40);
    return 0;
}
```